# ubuntu 16.04 "Package exfat-utils is not available, but is referred to by another package."

Tags: ubuntu, sd-card

This is my first time trying Linux so I don't know really anything and could use some help with using exFAT sd cards on ubuntu 16.04.

A little information first, I'm running ubuntu from my flash drive and I'm using UNetbootin to set up the iso. When setting up the iso I reserve about 3 gb.

What I'm trying to do is be able to use my SD card but it says it's unable to read exFAT files when I plug it in.

I've tried :

```
sudo apt-get install exfat-fuse exfat-utils
```

but it doesn't work, here is the output:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install exfat-fuse exfat-utils
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package exfat-utils is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Unable to locate package exfat-fuse
E: Package 'exfat-utils' has no installation candidate
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Also let me know if you need more information to solve this issue.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Have you [enabled the universe repository](http://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)?

Answer (score 4):

To install [`exfat-utils`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/+source/exfat-utils) and [`extfat-fuse`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fuse-exfat/1.2.3-1) you need to enable the `universe` repository :

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) universe"
```

On the newest Ubuntu versions (@linolino answer and @paradite comment) :

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
```

Update and install it:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install exfat-fuse exfat-utils
```

Comment: I found a similar solution in another thread which solved the problem: `sudo add-apt-repository universe`

Answer (score 2):

For me same issue :

```
sudo apt-get install exfat-fuse exfat-utils
```

Unfortunately answer from GAD3R did not work (not sure why)

so as paradite commented the simpler way worked for me

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install exfat-fuse exfat-utils
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/231556)

Comment: @datUser on the newest Ubuntu version the correct command is `sudo add-apt-repository universe`

Answer (score 2):

From [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403900/how-to-install-exfat-utils-and-hddtemp-on-ubuntu-22-04), since Ubuntu 22.04 exfat-utils has been replaced by exfatprogs.

```
sudo apt install exfatprogs
```